# continuously background service in react native

Tags: react-native

I have an app that get notification from signal R.In foreground I dont have problem and it works.When the app is in background I want to have background service that always listen to signal R notification.(Signal R notifications fail if the user is offline). Packages in react native dont do it .I try with Headless but it does not work properly.
This is my service.

```
enter code here  public class Service extends HeadlessJsTaskService {
@Nullable
protected HeadlessJsTaskConfig getTaskConfig(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        return new HeadlessJsTaskConfig(
                "service",
                Arguments.fromBundle(extras),
                5000);
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

And in MainApplication inside create method i call it.

```
enter code here  Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, com.Myservice.Service.class);
            serviceIntent.putExtra("hasInternet", hasInternet);
            context.startService(serviceIntent);
            HeadlessJsTaskService.acquireWakeLockNow(context);
```